# how to get a fingerprint from my android device

Tags: android

I would like to get a fingerprint from my android device ?

I have done a research it gave me following command :

C:>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\abc_username.android\debug
.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

I would not think the above command is my answer ? what does about command do ?

Comment: What do you mean by fingerprint? That debug keystore command is for getting a "debug keystore" that you would use in your development apps. When you make a market ready release you would create a normal keystore which you put a series of passwords into. If you want a unique identifier just google search for something like "how do I get a UID from device android"

Answer (score 1):

see this link, it explains obtaining Maps API key through MD5 fingerprint with debug .keystore of Android:
http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/apiKey.html

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey#getfingerprint)

With the following command you dont generate Fingerprint (MD5 Fingerprint more specifically) 
for you android device. You generate MD5 Fingerprint against keystore (C:\Users\abc_username.android\debug .keystore in your case) you are using for android development.

```
C:>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\abc_username.android\debug .keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

In Android this Fingerprint is useful to get Google Map api key which we can use in MapView.

If you change keystore, you will have to regenerate this fingerprint regarding to new keystore for getting api key from Google for MapView

About keytool

> keytool is a key and certificate management utility. It enables users to administer their own public/private key pairs and associated certificates for use in self-authentication (where the user authenticates himself/herself to other users/services) or data integrity and authentication services, using digital signatures. It also allows users to cache the public keys (in the form of certificates) of their communicating peers.

Hope this will help you